# Ubuntu 22.04 Plex Hardware transcode

Tags: video, intel, plex, 4k-monitor

I'm trying to set up a Plex on an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop with Intel N5105 (11th gen), 8GB ram. I cannot figure out how to activate hardware transcoding in Plex (Yes the option is ticked in Plex), 4K videos are stuttering when trying to convert them and I can see that there are no "hw" in the description.
I manage to read 4K HDR video in VLC after installing intel drivers, but 4K videos are not working on youtube (either on Firefox or Chrome).

Here are the vainfo, it seems right for me :
[vainfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVuw5.png)
When trying to play a 4K youtube video, here what i see from the igpu :
[igpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0rBs.png) it seems to be working but struggling..

I also have windows on this machine on another partition and I can read 4K videos just fine. I'm total newbie in Linux, I read a lot of topics to get this far (Veven LC was not able at first to read 4k videos...)
On firefox I tried what is explained there, but still the same issues : https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/enabling-accelerated-video-decoding-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-21-04/22081

I'm stucked right now, does not know what to do.

Any advice would be welcome !

Thanks

Comment: N5105 is a 10 W Celeron processor, and is hardly a good choice for video transcoding of any kind, especially 4K videos. It might work better with 480p videos, so try some of those.

Comment: No it's a perfecly fine CPU to handle 4K. 4k videos work fine in VLC, and works fine in youtube in WIndows.
Also someone tried it with sucess : 
https://chuckdickey.com/2022/03/performance-testing-plex-hardware-transcoding-with-a-jasper-lake-intel-celeron-n5105-cpu-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: Of cause your CPU is perfectly fine, although it is also somewhat inexpensive and low powered, when objectively compaired to other 11-gen CPUs. Also, a quick look through Chuck's "amazing revelations" reveals a suggestion related to i915 options, which you might want to consult.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

I manage to finally make it work by using 5.16 kernel and doing those steps :
Create and then edit the file:

/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf
Add the line below and save the file:

options i915 enable_guc=2
then run this command:

sudo update-initramfs -u

Every video is transcoding well in HW mode. Only issues remaining is that it buffers when I have subtitles, i'll have to get into that